How to import ChangeNotifier from Flutter into a console app?
I'm developing a console application that shares classes with a Flutter frontend. However, the classes inherit from ChangeNotifier (from flutter/foundation.dart). When I try to build the console app, it fails with an error saying the project cannot use dart:ui.
How can I import ChangeNotifier in a way that avoids the dart:ui error?

The only references to dart:ui are to provide the VoidCallback type, you could copy the whole ChangeNotifier source to your project and just remove/change the references to VoidCallback.
